# Tomato Plant Growth Plan - Help

Tags: tomatoes

I'm new to growing tomatoes. One of my plants is doing pretty good and I'm not sure what I should do with it.  I think my options are to cut the tops and let it bush out, or train it over onto the trellis of the neighbor plants (which are not doing as well).

Here is a picture:
[image]

Comment: What breed (or variety/cultivar) is it?

Answer (score 2):

I think I can see 6 tops. Most of those need to be regularly pruned off
to let the plant know it's supposed to produce fruit instead of a tangled mess of leaves. This action needs to be performed weekly.

What I find neat is that by choosing which top/s to leave uncut the gardener shapes the plant to their liking.

And on the topic of leaning on other plants. The tomato is a grass (vine). It can't stand on it's own, let alone bear the weight of the fruit. Either add a vertical stake for the plant to climb OR suspend some string from above and tie it up.

And concerning a growth plan you need to both answer @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx and to state your climate. If frost falls at winter (and the plant cannot be taken indoors) - plan for it to die at that time. Else ... idk, ask a separate question how to grow indeterminate tomatoes at tropical climate.

[image]